# Sapper Svelte Dist folder with Webpack.config.js

Tags: webpack, svelte, sapper

I am struggling to create a dist folder with webpack.config.js for my sapper svelte project, and yes I know with sapper all you have to do is run the build command for building and export to create the static folder in __ sapper __

But I am trying to run Webpack to build a dist folder just like you do with React, this is my entry:

```
  "entry": {
  main: path.join(__dirname, 'src', "client")
}
```

In sapper that file is:

```
import * as sapper from '@sapper/app';
export let target = document.querySelector('#sapper')
sapper.start({target})
```

Which is the equivalent of this in react:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

Problem is, when I run Webpack I get a syntax error:

```
WARNING in ./src/client.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/svelte-loader/index.js):
'target' is not defined. Consider adding a <script> block with 'export let target' to declare a prop (3:14)
1: import * as sapper from '@sapper/app';
2: export let target = document.querySelector('#sapper')
3: sapper.start({target});
                 ^
```

Comment: Do you have a `<div id="sapper"></div>` in your `index.html`?

Comment: Yes, of course, I think It cant be done with webpack.